# systemd: user service starts at boot with target default/graphical but not multi-user

Tags: linux, systemd

I tried to start at boot a service running in my user's context, which did not work with ***multi-user*** as target but only with ***default***, i.e., ***graphical***.

I enabled lingering for my user and the service

```
sudo loginctl enable-linger $USER
systemctl --user enable $SERVCE
systemctl --user start $SERVICE
```

However, the service did not got started after reboots.

The service originally targeted ***multi-user***

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

i.e., resulting in the service link

```
$HOME/.config/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/SERVICE.service
```

Not as expected, the service did not got started at boot.

Only after changing the target to ***default***

```
WantedBy=default.target
```

(which is currently ***graphical***) and re-enabling the service, the service got started automatically.

However, I had assumed that ***graphical*** is downstream of ***multi-user*** as target, i.e., being 'later', or?

What may be have prevented the service to start with ***multi-user***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man 7 systemd.special`,

> SPECIAL USER UNITS.
>
> ```
>   When systemd runs as a user instance, the following special units are
>   available, which have similar definitions as their system counterparts:
>
>   default.target, shutdown.target, sockets.target, timers.target,
>   paths.target, bluetooth.target, printer.target, smartcard.target,
>   sound.target.
> ```

So there is no user multi-user.target.

Comment: ah, thanks! I had implicitly assumed, that the states for users are the equivalent to the system! Good to know about it - as potential pitfall!

Comment: Would you suggest to use `default.target` for `WantedBy=` in `.service` , and `timers.target` in `timer` ? as in https://niels.kobschaetzki.net/blog/2015/11/11/creating-systemd-timers-instead-of-a-personal-crontab/

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki  I dont think the `.service` has a `WantedBy=`, as it will always be called explicitly from the timer unit. But the examples I have put a `Wants=....timer` in the `[Unit]` part of the `.service`.

Comment: Btw. Why do I see `multi-user.target` in pastebin.com/8B5jLUkz output of systemd-analyze critical-chain ? (I am using Arch Linux -> maybe it's distro specific?)