# How to start user systemd.timer (s) automatically?

Tags: configuration, systemd-timer

I have setup few user systemd.timer(s).

How to make them start automatically ? (either on system start or once user logged into X session).

After I restart of the system (even `systemctl --user enable` was run before restart, i.e. does not help) I have none running:

```
~$ systemctl --user enable {rsync_backup1,rsync_another_backup}.timer 
~$ systemctl --user list-timers --all
0 timers listed.
```

Here I commands I need to use to start them after :

```
~$ systemctl --user start {rsync_backup1,rsync_another_backup}.timer           
~$ systemctl --user list-timers --all
NEXT                          LEFT         LAST                          PASSED UNIT                          
Sun 2016-07-31 13:26:45 CEST  1h 16min ago Sun 2016-07-31 14:43:32 CEST  2s ago rsync_backup1
Sun 2016-07-31 13:26:45 CEST  1h 16min ago Sun 2016-07-31 14:43:32 CEST  2s ago rsync_another_backup

2 timers listed.
~$
```

Here is example how timers are currently configured :

$HOME/.config/systemd/user/rsync_backup1.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=rsync --delete /home/USER data to NASUSER@NAS

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/USER/scripts/rsync_backup1.sh
```

$HOME/.config/systemd/user/rsync_backup1.timer :

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs every 12 minutes rsync --delete /home/USER data to NASUSER@NAS

[Timer]
OnBootSec=12min
AccuracySec=10min
OnCalendar=*:0/12
Unit=rsync_backup1.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

P.S. Yes, I know I can drop commands, which start my timers into `.bashrc` or `.xinit` or my Window Manager "startup" scripts. What I am asking is: is there "systemd" "clean" way to define this to run after every restart (/login) ?

Comment: There is no user `multi-user.target`. See my [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297835/119298)

Comment: Therefore, what do I see it in http://pastebin.com/8B5jLUkz output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` ? (I am using Arch Linux -> maybe it's distro specific?)

Comment: You are missing the crucial point: the multi-user.target does not exist for *user* systemd units, i.e. those launched with `systemctl --user`. Of course, for "root" systemd, there is a  multi-user.target.

Comment: I assume it should be `default.target`, in the .timer units. Also do you run an `enable` command or only `start`?

Comment: Good point, I've added info to question that I was using `enable` and it does not help.

Answer (score 5):

**First**, like others said, you'll want to have them be installed with `WantedBy=default.target` instead of `WantdBy=multi-user.target`. This is the standard way to allow enabling of user units.

**But also, if you want them to start on boot,** see [this ArchWiki entry about starting systemd user units on boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances) instead of being tied to login.

In short:

```
# loginctl enable-linger username
```

(By the way, `Unit=rsync_backup1.service` is redundant since the timer and service file have the same base name)